# How to access the publishing credentials of a website using Azure RM and ResourceId

Tags: powershell, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to get the publishing credentials of a website using AzureRm and PowerShell using `Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction` and PowerShell.

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34521406/414145) @David Ebbo explains how to do it using `ResourceName` and `ResourceGroupName` as parameters of the `Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction` cmdlet. I've tried that and it works perfectly and the object I get back has an Id property that looks a lot like a `ResourceId`. 
I've tried using that Id as the `ResourceId` parameter and removing `ResourceName` and `ResourceGroupName` but I get an error saying the resource doesn't exist.

I'd like to use `ResourceId` because I need to automate this for a series of Websites in different resource groups and I only have (easy) access to the `ResourceId` (and the `ResourceId` of the website looks really similar to the Id of the publishing credentials object I get using `ResourceName` and `ResourceGroupName`).

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the more complete output of the command? That might help identify the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working fine for me with the following command:

```
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceId /subscriptions/$sub/resourceGroups/$rg/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$sitename/config/publishingcredentials -Action list -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force -Debug
```

Comment: I found what was going on. The id I get from running it with ResourceName is something like this `/subscriptions/$id/resourceGroups/$rg/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$website/publishingcredentials/$website`

I tried removing the `$website` at the end but I was missing a `/config/` between `/$website` and `/publishingprofile`

Thanks!