# Azure Web App - upload package from powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

I've used `New-AzureRmWebApp` to create WebApp from `powershell`. But I don't find any `cmdlet` to upload package to created Azure Web App :( Looking for AzureRm cmdlet in specific.

Comment: which package are you talking about?

Comment: I've an application package(.zip), generated by publishing web project to a physical folder.

Comment: According to [official documnt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.websites/v2.7.0/azurerm.websites), currently we can't find AzureRM Powershell command to support upload package directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are co-admin of your subscription,you can use command `Publish-AzureWebsiteProject -Name site1 -Package .\WebApplication1.zip` to do that.We also can use [kudu Rest API (Zip)](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API).More detail about how to get authorization please refer to another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27443368/azure-websites-kudu-rest-api-authentication)

kudu Rest Api sample code:

```
$website = Get-AzureWebsite -Name "WebAppSampleFtn2"
$username = $website.PublishingUsername
$password = $website.PublishingPassword
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$password)))
$userAgent = "powershell/1.0"
$apiBaseUrl = "https://$($website.Name).scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/wwwroot"
$filePath = "D:\package\PackageTmp.zip"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiBaseUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -UserAgent $userAgent -Method PUT -InFile $filePath -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: Am looking for AzureResourceManager cmdlet in specific. 
Publish-AzureWebsiteProject requires me to setup my subscription again

Comment: it looks like there is not suitable AzureRM cmdlet to upload package to create azure web app.we can use kudu Rest API (Zip) to do that. here is sample code have tested to be work.