# How to update the settings.job via the scm.azurewebsites.net REST API?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

We are looking to use slots in our Web App, and want to do a slot swap. We have jobs that run on schedule. When we swap the slot, we need to have the job run on the correct schedule for that environment/

What is the recommended way to update the schedule? The preferred approach is to use PowerShell.

Comment: You could use the Kudu vfs API to just replace the one file

Comment: @DavidEbbo How about using REST based file service API to update the files using powershell ?

Comment: That's wah Kuud vfs API is. Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David Ebbo commented that you could leverage the Kudu [WebJobs API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API) about **Set the schedule for a triggered job** as follows:

```
PUT /api/triggeredwebjobs/{job name}/settings

Body {"schedule": "0 */2 * * * *"}
```

> What is the recommended way to update the schedule? The preferred approach is to use PowerShell.

You could leverage the following command:

```html
$username = "<username>"
$password = "<password>"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$password)))
$contentType='application/json'
$data= @{
   schedule='*/30 * * * * *'
}
$body = $data | ConvertTo-JSON

$apiUrl = "https://<your-appname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/<job-name>/settings"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method Put -Body $body -ContentType $contentType
```

Moreover, you could refer to this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27443368/azure-websites-kudu-rest-api-authentication).