# Deploying Web Jobs Using ARM or the Powershell Script

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, powershell-2.0

I am trying to deploy Web job in to Azure using powershell script where we have our own deployment Framework, when i am deploying from my local machine it is deploying successfully only if i have the Admin or Co- Admin permissions if i have contributor Access script fails.Our deployment framework has only contributor permissions, Is there any way to deploy web job with the contributor permissions and I didn't found any ARM templates for Web Job deployment where i have solution file in local . Any suggestions please
Here is my script

```
`Add-AzureAccount (since web job doesn't have any RM commandlett i am using classic login where All our resource are in RM )
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "*************"

$packageSource ="$Global:packageDir/../output\deletelogs\bin"

$destinationSource = "$env:TEMP\DeleteLogsWebjob.zip"

If(Test-path $destinationSource) {Remove-item $destinationSource}

Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"

[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($packageSource, $destinationSource) 

$webappname = AzCreateWebAppName "mywebapp$(Get-Random)"

$location =   "EastUs"           #GetCurrentRegion

$resourceGroupName= "*****"           # AzGetResourceGroup

$webjobName = $webappname +"_deletelogsjob"

$jobCollecctionName = $webappname + $webjobName + "JobCollection"

#<### Defining Schedules
#$date = Get-Date 
#$startDate = $date.ToString("MM-dd-yyy HH:mm tt")
#$endDate = $date.AddYears(1).ToString("MM-dd-yyy HH:mm tt")#>

# #Create an App Service plan in Free tier.
New-AzureRmAppServicePlan -Name $webappname -Location $location -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Tier Basic

## Create a web app.
$webapp = New-AzureRmWebApp -Name $webappname -Location $location -AppServicePlan $webappname -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName

###### Create WebJob

$job = New-AzureWebsiteJob -Name $webapp -JobName $webjobName -JobType Triggered -JobFile $destinationSource

$jobCollection = New-AzureRmSchedulerJobCollection -Location $location -JobCollectionName $jobCollecctionName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName

$temp = "$env:TEMP\appsetting.xml"

$file = Get-AzureRMWebAppPublishingProfile -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $webappname -OutputFile $temp -Format WebDeploy


$webSitePassword = ([xml]$file).ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[0].Attributes[5].Value


$webSiteUserName = ([xml]$file).ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[0].Attributes[4].Value

$uri = "https://{0}:{1}@{2}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/{3}/run" -f $webSiteUserName, $webSitePassword,$webappname, $webjobName

New-AzureRmSchedulerHttpJob -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
  -JobCollectionName $jobCollection[0].JobCollectionName -JobName "deleteLogsScheduler" -Method POST `
  -URI $uri -StartTime $startDate -Interval 2 -Frequency Minute `
  -EndTime $endDate`
```

Comment: Do you check this [example](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-a-WebJob-using-PowerShell-ARM-Cmdlets)? You should use ARM cmdlet not mixed using ARM and classic cmdlet.

Comment: May be that’s the issue using both Arm and classic in same code and the code you gave have some kudu authorization which I don’t get , if you have any reference can you please share it.

Comment: I update my answer. You could check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27443368/azure-websites-kudu-rest-api-authentication).

Comment: Your script works good in my local  but our deployment framework doesn't support kudu, is there any alternate way without using kudu as a regular powershell script.

Comment: Hi, your framework does not support Kudu, what do you mean? Azure web app all supports kudu. If possible, you could ask a new question about your detailed scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use example in this [blog](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-a-WebJob-using-PowerShell-ARM-Cmdlets).

```
#Resource details :
$resourceGroupName = "<Resourcegroup name>";
$webAppName = "<WebApp name>";
$Apiversion = 2015-08-01

#Function to get Publishing credentials for the WebApp :
function Get-PublishingProfileCredentials($resourceGroupName, $webAppName){

$resourceType = "Microsoft.Web/sites/config"
$resourceName = "$webAppName/publishingcredentials"
$publishingCredentials = Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceType 
$resourceType -ResourceName $resourceName -Action list -ApiVersion $Apiversion -Force
   return $publishingCredentials
}

#Pulling authorization access token :
function Get-KuduApiAuthorisationHeaderValue($resourceGroupName, $webAppName){

$publishingCredentials = Get-PublishingProfileCredentials $resourceGroupName $webAppName
return ("Basic {0}" -f [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f 
$publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingUserName, $publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingPassword))))
}

$accessToken = Get-KuduApiAuthorisationHeaderValue $resourceGroupName $webAppname
#Generating header to create and publish the Webjob :
$Header = @{
'Content-Disposition'='attachment; attachment; filename=Copy.zip'
'Authorization'=$accessToken
        }
$apiUrl = "https://$webAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/<Webjob-type>/<Webjob-name>"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers $Header -Method put -InFile "<Complete path of the file>\
<filename>.zip" -ContentType 'application/zip' 
#NOTE: Update the above script with the parameters highlighted and run in order to push a new Webjob under the specified WebApp.
```

For Kudu authorization

```
$creds = Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName YourResourceGroup -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName YourWebApp/publishingcredentials -Action list -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force

$username = $creds.Properties.PublishingUserName
$password = $creds.Properties.PublishingPassword
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$password)))

$apiBaseUrl = "https://$($website.Name).scm.azurewebsites.net/api"

$kuduVersion = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$apiBaseUrl/environment" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method GET
```

Answer (score 0):

This following lines of code is power shell script which allows you to deploy webjob in a web app . The parameters are passed through the settings file reference ...

```
#Requires -Version 3.0

Param(
    [string] $settingsFileName = '\Settings\settings.json',
    [boolean] $unitTestMode = $false
    )
$Apiversion = "2015-08-01"
# Define FUNCTIONS

#Check if any requirement is missing
function Test-ParameterSet
{
    param
    (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][System.Object]$settings
    )
    # Loop through the $settings and check no missing setting
    if ($null -eq $applicationFileJson.subscriptions) {throw "Missing subscriptions field in settings file"}
    foreach ($subscription in $applicationFileJson.subscriptions)
    {
        if ($null -eq $subscription.subscriptionId) {throw "Missing subscription Id field in settings file"}
        # Loop through the $settings and check no missing setting
        foreach ($vault in $settings.WorkLoads)
        {
            if ($null -eq $vault.applicationName) {throw "Missing applicationNam in settings file for $($subscription.subscriptionId)"}
            if ($null -eq $vault.environmentName) {throw "Missing environmentName in settings file for $($subscription.subscriptionId)"}
            if ($null -eq $vault.resourceGroupName) {throw "Missing resourceGroupName in settings file for $($subscription.subscriptionId)"}
            if ($null -eq $vault.webAppName) {throw "Missing webAppName in settings file for $($subscription.subscriptionId)"}
            if ($null -eq $vault.Storagerg) {throw "Missing Storagerg in settings file for $($subscription.subscriptionId)"}
            if ($null -eq $vault.webjobname) {throw "Missing webjobname in settings file for $($subscription.subscriptionId)"}
            if ($null -eq $vault.webjobtype) {throw "Missing webjobtype in settings file for $($subscription.subscriptionId)"}
            if ($null -eq $vault.storageAccountName) {throw "Missing storageAccountName in settings file for $($subscription.subscriptionId)"}
            if ($null -eq $vault.container_name) {throw "Missing container_name in settings file for $($subscription.subscriptionId)"}
            If ($vault.webjobtype -eq "triggeredwebjobs")
            {
                if ($null -eq $vault.trigger_type) {throw "Missing trigger_type in settings file for $($subscription.subscriptionId)"}
            }
            }

            If ($vault.webjobtype -eq "triggeredwebjobs" -and $vault.trigger_type -eq "scheduled") 
            {
                 if ($null -eq $vault.schedule) {throw "Missing schedule in settings file for $($subscription.subscriptionId)"}

            If ($vault.webjobtype -eq "continuouswebjobs") 
            {
                 if ($null -eq $vault.continuous_type) {throw "Missing continuous_type in settings file for $($subscription.subscriptionId)"}
            }
    } 
    return $true
} 
}




function Get-KuduApiAuthorisationHeaderValue($resourceGroupName, $webAppName)
{ 
$resourceType = "Microsoft.Web/sites/config"
$resourceName = "$webAppName/publishingcredentials"
$publishingCredentials = Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceType $resourceType -ResourceName $resourceName -Action list -ApiVersion $Apiversion -Force
return ("Basic {0}" -f [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingUserName, $publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingPassword))))
}


function Publish-webjob
{ 

        [OutputType([String])]
    param
    (
         [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$resourceGroupName,
         [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$webAppName,
         [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$Storagerg,
         [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$webjobname,
         [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$webjobtype,
         [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$storageAccountName,

         [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$container_name,
         [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$settingsFileName,
         [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$i

    )  

    #Check resource group exist
    try {
        $resourceGroup = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName -ErrorAction Stop   
    }
    catch {
        $resourceGroup = $null
    }
    if ($null -eq $resourceGroup)
    {
        $message = "Resource group $resourceGroupName not found, deployment stop"
        Write-Verbose $message
        return $message
    }   
        else 
    {
        # Prepare deployment variables
        Write-Verbose "ResourceGroup Found"

        $SettingsJson = Get-JsonParameterSet -settingsFileName $settingsFileName
        $trigger_type = "$($SettingsJson.WorkLoads[$i].trigger_type)"
        Write-Verbose $trigger_type
        $schedule = "$($SettingsJson.WorkLoads[$i].schedule)"
        Write-Verbose $schedule
        $continuous_type = "$($SettingsJson.WorkLoads[$i].continuous_type)"
        Write-Verbose $continuous_type
    }

    # Unlock ResourceGroup
                    Unlock-ResourceGroup $resourceGroupName
                    write-verbose "ResourceGroup Unlocked"

    $accessToken = Get-KuduApiAuthorisationHeaderValue $resourceGroupName $webAppname


    #Get storage account context and storage bolo
    $sa= Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $Storagerg -Name $storageAccountName
    $ctx=$sa.Context
    $blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $container_name -Context $ctx
    $webjobtype=$webjobtype+"webjobs"
    $apiUrl = "https://$webAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/$webjobtype/$webjobname"


    #create a folder to save all the files of the container
    $Location=$PSScriptRoot

    New-Item -Path $Location -Name $webjobname -ItemType "directory" -Force
    $folderPath = "$Location"+"\"+$webjobname
    $localFile = $Location+"\"+$webjobname+"\"


    #Generating header to create and publish the Webjob :
    $Header = @{
    "Content-Disposition"="attachment;filename=$($webAppName)"
    "Authorization"=$accessToken
            }
    #Check if the storage container is empty
    If($blobs.Count -eq 0)
    {
        Write-Error  "The storage container is found empty"  
    }

    #get files from container
    foreach ($blob in $blobs)
    {   
        $file=New-TemporaryFile
        $file=Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container $container_name -Blob $blob.Name -Context $ctx -Destination $localFile -Force
        $contents = Get-Content $localFile -Raw -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue
        $f=New-TemporaryFile
        Add-Content $f $contents
    }

    If ($webjobtype -eq "triggeredwebjobs" -and $trigger_type -eq "scheduled") 
    {

            $f = New-TemporaryFile 
            $r="{ ""schedule"" : "+""""+ $schedule+"""" + "}"
            Add-Content $f $r
            $destination=$Location+"\"+$webjobname+"\settings.job"

            Move-Item -Path $f -Destination $destination
    }


    If ($webjobtype -eq "continuouswebjobs") 
    {

        $f = New-TemporaryFile 
        If($continuous_type -eq "singleinstance")
        {
            $c="true"
        }
        If($continuous_type -eq "multipleinstance")
        {
            $c="false"
        }
        $r="{ ""is_singleton"" : " + $c + "}"
        Add-Content $f $r
        $destination=$Location+"\"+$webjobname+"\settings.job"
        Move-Item -Path $f -Destination $destination

    }

    #Archive the files to a zip
    $source = $localFile + "*"
    $wz=$webjobname+".zip"
    $destination = $Location+"\"+$webjobname+"\"+$wz
    Compress-Archive -U -Path $source -DestinationPath $destination

    #Deploying webjobs
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers $Header  -Method put -InFile $destination -ContentType 'application/zip'  -ErrorAction Stop 
    Write-Host "Print result " -ForegroundColor Green


    #delete the folder from local mahine
    Remove-Item $folderPath -Force  -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue


    # lock ResourceGroup
                #Lock-ResourceGroup $resourceGroupName
                write-verbose "ResourceGroup locked"

    return $result

}



function Publish-Infrastructure
{
param(
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$settingsFileName
     )

    $settings = Get-JsonParameterSet -settingsFileName $settingsFileName
    $deploymentIsSucceeded = $true
    $workloadCount = $settings.WorkLoads.Count
    Write-Verbose "workloadCounts: $workloadCount"
    if($workloadCount -ge 1)
    {
        for($i = 0;$i -lt $workloadCount; $i++)
            { 

                $applicationName = $settings.WorkLoads[$i].applicationName
                Write-Verbose "application name: $applicationName"
                $environmentName = $settings.WorkLoads[$i].environmentName
                $applicationFile = "..\SettingsByWorkload\" + "nv_" + $applicationName + ".workload.json"
                $applicationFile = Get-FileFullPath -fileName $applicationFile  -rootPath $PSScriptRoot
                $applicationFileJson = Get-JsonParameterSet -settingsFileName $applicationFile
                Write-Verbose "application file json: $applicationName"
                $null = Test-ParameterSet -settings $settings

                $policyCount = $applicationFileJson.subscriptions.Count
                Write-Verbose "$policyCount"
                if($policyCount -ge 1)
                {  
                    for($j = 0;$j -lt $policyCount; $j++)
                    { 


                        if($applicationFileJson.subscriptions[$j].environmentName -eq $environmentName)
                        {    

                            $subscriptionId = $applicationFileJson.subscriptions[$j].subscriptionId 
                            Write-Verbose "Environment Subscription: $($subscriptionId)"
                            Set-ContextIfNeeded -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
                            foreach ($webjob in $settings.WorkLoads[$i])
                            {                   
                                                $resourceGroupName = $webjob.resourceGroupName
                                                $webAppName = $webjob.webAppName
                                                $Storagerg = $webjob.Storagerg
                                                $webjobname = $webjob.webjobname
                                                $webjobtype = $webjob.webjobtype
                                                $storageAccountName = $webjob.storageAccountName
                                                $schedule = $webjob.schedule
                                                $container_name = $webjob.container_name
                                                $trigger_type = $webjob.trigger_type
                                                Write-Verbose "Ready to start deployment on environment $EnvironmentName of a webjob in subscription $subscriptionId for resource group: $resourceGroupName"

                                                $result = Publish-webjob ` -resourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
                                                -webAppName $webAppName `
                                                -Storagerg $Storagerg `
                                                -webjobname $webjobname `
                                                -webjobtype $webjobtype `
                                                -storageAccountName $storageAccountName `
                                                -settingsFileName $settingsFileName `
                                                -container_name $container_name `
                                                -i $i

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }        
            }

    }

        return $true

}


#START OF SCRIPT
if ($unitTestMode)
{
    #do nothing
    Write-Verbose 'Unit test mode, no deployment' -Verbose
}
else 
{
  #Log in Azure if not already done
    try 
    {
        $azureRmContext = Get-AzureRmContext -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch 
    {
        $result = Add-AzureRmAccount
        $azureRmContext = $result.Context
    }
    Write-Verbose "Subscription name $($azureRmContext.Subscription.Name)" -Verbose
    $VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

    # Get required templates and setting files. Throw if not found
    $scriptsPath=$PSScriptRoot

    $scriptsPath = Split-Path -Path $scriptsPath -Parent  


    $SettingsPath = Join-Path $scriptsPath $settingsFileName

    $settingsFileName = $SettingsPath



    Write-Verbose "Settings file name $($settingsFileName)" -Verbose

    # Deploy infrastructure
    return Publish-Infrastructure `
        -settingsFileName $settingsFileName `

# END of script
}
```